# Neither..nor/ Either..or with contradictive sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, negation

I don't know how to explain these sentences. But my teacher gave me this problem of combining two sentences using neither-nor or either-or:

> 1. I will attend the party.
> 2. If I can't, my sister will.

How do you combine those using neither-nor or either-or? My best try is

> I will either attend the party, or if I can't my sister will.

Comment: Before just giving you the answer, do you have any ideas of what it might be?

Comment: Also, "either-nor"?  Usually it's "neither-nor"...

Comment: @Victor I think that must just be a typo (as it's correct in the title) - fixed in the proposed edit.

Answer (score 1):

Either/or is for use in positive situations:

> Either my sister or I will attend the party

I.E. *someone* will attend

Neither/nor is for use in negative situations:

> Neither my sister nor I will attend the party

I.E. No one is going. It may help to think of the 'n's in neither/nor as being conflated or borrowed from "not".

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is close, but it doesn't fit the pattern expected from you, I believe.

> I will either attend the party, or if I can't my sister will.

When you put "**either**" *after* "**will**", you essentially specify that there are two (mutually exclusive) actions that you **will** take.  The description of the first follows the "**either**", and according to the use of "*either-or*", the description of the other ought to follow the "**or**".  For instance,

> I will **either** run the 10K **or** swim the relay (but not both).
>   He will **either** reach the top **or** die trying.

In other words, the exclusive portions each *follows* the "**either**" and the "**or**" in the sentence.  If, as you describe, you might attend (one portion), and in case you're unable, your sister will, then you need to wrap those into parts to *follow* the "key" words:

> **Either** I will attend the party, **or**, if I am unable, my sister will.